# > sign inside OBIEE GO URL?

Tags: oracle, http, url, curl, obiee

I am trying to use a '>' symbol inside a GOURL to retrieve a report in PDF format automatically to users desktop. I'm actually using a perl script to programmatically request the login page, login using my credentials, and then I use a go url to download pdf report, sending it parameters,(doing URL encoding which includes converting '>' to '%3E' ,which winds up looking something like:

```
HTTP://bi.ourcompany.com/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBAZV2%2F%5Fportal%2FBAR%20%28BAZZER%29&Page=BAZZER%20BAR%20Report&Action=Navigate&format=pdf&P0=3&P1=eq&P2=Bing.Baz&P3=%3EVAL1%5F03&P4=eq&P5=VAL2&P6=08%2F31%2F2010&P7=eq&P8=Zaz.Zaz&P9=BAR
```

One thing to note: I could not get this working at all using 'GO' instead of 'Dashboard'. I also had to use Action= 'Navigate' instead of 'print' to make this work. (When I use 'Go' Instead of 'Dashboard', I get an empty PDF file which says something about 'no columns could be rendered'. That's OK though, because it works just fine, except when there's a '>' symbol in one of the parameter values...

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repace > with `%3E`

http://w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: thanks. That's exactly what my url encode regex was doing - but the url doesnt retreive the report as expected. Must be specific OBIEE / GO URL issue, which are very difficult to find resources on..

Comment: could you please edit your post so i could downvote this, otherwise im basically throwing away 100 bounty points if no one comes up with the answer.... (they need to fix the bounty system...)

Comment: @dferraro: not sure it makes any difference, according to http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty you lose the bounty amount even if it isn't awarded to an answer; and would only automatically go to an +2 answer created after the bounty started anyway.

Comment: I wont get the bounty since I answered before the bounty.  good luck

Comment: @Tihom: I believe you could post a second answer with the same text.